# Is it true that $\sup(Y) - \sup(X) \leq \sup(Y \setminus X)$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two subsets not empty of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $X \subset Y$

Is it true that:
$$
\sup(Y) - \sup(X) \leq \sup(Y \setminus X)
$$

thanks.

Comment: maybe i'm stupid but i see it slippery

Comment: Hint: Don't forget negative numbers....

Comment: @MichaelBurr thanks so much, now i realize where i was wrong, $X$ and $Y$ have only positive numbers.

Comment: That's a pretty important circumstance.  You should add that to the Question itself if you want Readers to appreciate your problem setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course this is false. Look at an example - if that example is not a counterexample you got very unlucky, look at another example.

There's really no reason I can imagine why anyone would think this was true; hence the question: Where did this question come from? I actually formulated a hypothesis about that. It *is* true that$$\sup(Y)-\sup(X)\le\sup(Y-X)$$(at least if $X\ne\emptyset$), where $$Y-X=\{y-x:y\in Y, x\in X\}.$$And unfortunately people do sometimes write $Y-X$ when they should write $Y\setminus X$. So I suppose someone *could* see that true formula and assume that $Y-X$ meant $Y\setminus X$...

Comment: thanks for your answer